# Error message "version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found" appears when running an INLA model in R

Tags: r, gcc, hpc, r-inla

In order to use the INLA R package in a HPC cluster,  I followed this [tutorial](https://www.r-inla.org/download-install). However, when trying to launch the test model, the following message appears:

> /storage/homefs/'username'/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/INLA/bin/linux/64bit/inla.mkl: /storage/homefs/'username'/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/INLA/bin/linux/64bit/first/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /software.el7/software/ICU/69.1-GCCcore-10.3.0/lib64/libicuuc.so.69)

I tried to load different version of GCC but the same issue remained. When trying it on my personal computer, it works fine. Did anyone have similar message?

Below is the script I used to test the INLA package in R:

```
library(INLA)

n = 100; a = 1; b = 1; tau = 100
z = rnorm(n)
eta = a + b*z

scale = exp(rnorm(n))
prec = scale*tau
y = rnorm(n, mean = eta, sd = 1/sqrt(prec))

data = list(y=y, z=z)
formula = y ~ 1+z
result = inla(formula, family = "gaussian", data = data)
summary(result)
```